# How to hide Youtube controls, title and logo on an embed

Tags: css, url, youtube, embed

I am interested in hiding everything about a Youtube embed.

Right now I am using the next URL params:

controls=0
showinfo=0

So when I try to add "modestbranding=1" it is not working. "showinfo" has priority over "modestbranding".

My question is...is there a way to hide everything with params or CSS?

The only part I need to hide right now is the Youtube logo at the bottom right of the video.

[image: IMG]

Answer (score 1):

http://www.reelseo.com/remove-youtube-logo/

has a decent tutorial and recommends using:

... src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID?modestbranding=1&title=" ...

what does the code around your embed look like?

Comment: As I said, I was using modestbranding=1 but combining it with showinfo=0 will not be effective. I will need another solution and I think it'll be something related with CSS.